# Magento 2.3 - LEMP - Nginx hosts - Backend & frondend url 404 error

Tags: nginx, magento2.3.4, localhost, linux

My LEMP localhost URL : **192.168.1.64:8087/giri** I want to stup multiwebsite so that i have configured url like **[www.giri.local](http://www.giri.local)** by using follow steps,

Nginx : etc/hosts

**192.168.1.64:8087 [www.giri.local](http://www.giri.local)**

After added above location my magento backend url changes to **[www.magento.local/admin_76tE](http://www.magento.local/admin_76tE)** and both Backend & frondend url 404 error

Error Screenshot : https://snipboard.io/dOtLuT.jpg